# Trying to checking if some user exists in my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures

I'm trying to check if some user exists in my database or not using this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE see_if_writer_exsists_or_not
   @username nvarchar(50),
   @password nvarchar(50) 
AS 
    select count(*) 
    from writers 
    where username = @username and password = @password
RETURN
```

Then I invoke it as a method using Linq-to-SQL with this code:

```
int b = DS.see_if_writer_exsists_or_not(username.Text, password.Text);

if (b > 0)
    { // the rest of the code...
```

but a conversion error appears

> Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult' to 'int'

How to fix this ?

**Note**: I've tried `Convert.ToInt32` method and it didn't work!

Comment: Please tell me you're **NOT STORING** password in **clear text** in your database!!!

Comment: yes I pass it to make sure if this account registered or not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no problem with the stored procedure! if u want to check about if this username and password exists
just check if your method returns values or not by using .count()

```
if (DS.see_if_writer_exsists_or_not(username.Text, password.Text).count() > 0) 
{
// yourcode...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this also to extract my retrieved record from the database by using `.ElementAt(0)`method ,and here is the update in my code :

```
DS.see_if_writer_exsists_or_not(username.Text, password.Text).ElementAt(0)
```

by using this I could get the first element retrieved and that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

It's just like the error message says:

1. Your call to `see_if_writer_exsists_or_not` returns an `ISingleResult` instance.
2. A call of `ToString()` returns `"System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult"` (which of course cannot be cast to an int).

You must return the query result from your stored proc and regenerate the `see_if_writer_exsists_or_not` method to accomplish what you want.

Comment: No. Nothing on the code side will work before you changed your stored procedure to return the desired value. Currently, it's just not available in code. Alternatively, you could do the same with a simple query: `select exists(select * from writers where username=@username and password=@password)`.

Comment: Hm.. the problem is the return type of the sp as I use Linq so I invoke it as a method .. and the return type still as it is ( doesn't want to be converted to bool or any other types )

Comment: its type is System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult !

Answer (score 0):

`ISingleResult` is an enumerable. You can loop through it using `foreach`. You can also do something like this:

```
ISingleResult<int> results = YourMethodCall();
int returnValue;

if(results.Count()>0){
returnValue = results.First<int>();
}
```

Also, please remove `ToString` call from your method call.

Comment: What is the type of ISingleResult that your method returns? Also, is null a possibility here?

Comment: see_if_writer_exsists_or_notRESULT (that's what appear to me ) ,and yes because the method may not find data for that writer ( means hen's not registered yet )